# How do I remove a member from my iOS Developer Team?

Tags: iphone, membership

I recently sent an invitation to an individual to join my iOS developer team. The accepted the invitation.  However, I would now like to remove them and I can't find a way to do so.  Currently, they have "member access" to my account but, due to concerns I have with this persons integrity I want to limit their access to my account.  Any help on how to delete this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: As this is an issue with Apple's provisioning website, it might be more appropriate for their developer forums: http://devforums.apple.com/ where I believe they have a subforum devoted to this.

Answer (score 4):

Took a while but I found it...

- Go to https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#allpeople
- From the list, check the boxes to the left of the people you wish to remove
- The 'Delete' button in the bottom-left corner now activates and you can press it
- Confirm delete!

I have a couple of accounts on "No Access" in case I need to get them back, but using the above method I successfully removed members who are no longer at the company.

Answer (score 3):

Go to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa) and sign in. Click on the link for Manage Users. Next click the Edit Profile button to the right of the user who you want to delete. You will then see a Delete User button in the top left corner that you can use to remove that user.

After that, you may also want to remove the user's [device(s)](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/devices/index.action) and [certificates](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action) from the iOS Provisioning Portal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, how do you "uninvite" them from being a member of the development team.  I removed them from iTunes connect, but they are still showing up as a member of my "development team".  I don't like that they can view everyone on my team as they seem to be a little off balanced.  Please help.

Comment: There may be a way to do so from the Member Center page (https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/), but I only have an individual account, so I'm not 100% sure. If the user still shows up after being deleted from iTunes Connect (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=manageAccounts), then contact Apple to request that they remove the user for you via http://developer.apple.com/contact/

Answer (score 1):

iTunes connect has nothing to do with that.

The only things you can do your self is to invite the member with some initial privileges that can be revoked later - although you can not restore them yourself.

To really remove the member from the team or to restore his access you should call the iphone dev center support by phone or contact them by e-mail.

Once I've added one of the members and needed to delete him - I has became crazy about it.

To my complete satisfaction a call to the worldwide developer center support did do the thing in 5 minutes or so. The fastest support I ever got from Apple! Thumbs up!