# How to remove Email ID from invited list in apple developer member account

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to remove the invited Email ID from my account. Is there anyway to do it? Or is it same as UDID where we cant delete them once its added.

[image]

One more question.. Does this email gets notification when my app is being uploaded or updated. Because I don't want them to get notification.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750428/how-do-i-remove-a-member-from-my-ios-developer-team

Comment: I think they will send mail to only your main account when your app is being uploaded or updated

Comment: @Rachit thanx for Reply.. I have seen answer of jowie on that link but in my case only two people display there form the list and doent display the delete button. I think lot control change with update.

Comment: But i think second answer which suggest the call will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can remove invited Email IDs from your member account. But for that you must be agent for that account. As you are saying that its your own account, so this might not be a problem for you. To withdraw go to the invitation section. There click on the details of the person invited. you can find link to withdraw invitation at right side of screen. I've attached screenshot. Let me know if more info needed 
[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: Even accepted account can be withdrawn? you see there is 1 id that is accepted.

Comment: And after i withdrawn them no notification will goes to that account?

Comment: yes.. no notification.. to make it sure, go to iOS developers section, & assign no access to particular account. Then they will not be able to access the account also

Comment: There is only two account one of them is client and other is me. Not that third accepted account.

Comment: Does that mean that account does not have permission to get notification.

Comment: If it is not there means it does not have access. so no notifications too.. .Anyhow, notifications are sent to only agents.. :)

Answer (score 0):

for your second question
I think they will send mail to only your main account when your app is being uploaded or updated